# How to share subdomain site using laravel valet?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I'm developing site with **subdomain**. I am using *laravel valet* as well So, It's currently look like `https://app.portal.test/` in my local environment. I want to share this site using *laravel valet* sharing site option [sharing-sites-via-ngrok](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#sharing-sites-via-ngrok). But it's not working. So I guess I want to do something different for sharing with **subdomain**. Anyone have any idea how to do for `valet share` for **subdomain**?

Comment: you can use direct ngrok commands to host a site at a particular port

Comment: @bhucho Can you give the step how to do that? or share any related doc. Thanks

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of valet but I can help with `sharing-sites-via-ngrok.` part answer

Comment: If you use ngrok to show your site, then the url will not remain `https://app.portal.test/` but will change to `https://4234rgsrgs.ngrok.io` where the subdomain is random string created for each terminal(command line) session, this is how ngrok works, the nest you can do is buy a subscription of ngrok, then you will get `your-name.ngrok.io` as https domain If you don't have any problem with that then you can use ngrok directly

Comment: @bhucho Thanks for your time. Actually I checked `laravel-valet`, `ngrok` and `expose` for this purpose. Actually i want to work with subdomain so the `ngrok` not free for subdomain share so i skip. What do you thing about `expose` any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR: You can't

You cant share https://app.portal.test (.test), thats for local only, it doesn't resolve on internet.

---

If you have public ip (whatsmyip.com) and that ip opens your localhost, then you can create a virtual host that point to that IP but you still need a real domain not test.

Using ngork is best option you have, You can also get a cheap $3 vps and point your domain to it.